# Do my wife and I need to update our marriage certificate if she changed her name 3 years after we married?

Tags: marriage

My wife recently legally changed her name after becoming a U.S. citizen. We've been married for 3 years already. How can we update our old marriage certificate from a different state? I'm assuming there might be some point in the future where we need to present a marriage certificate for something, but we don't urgently need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Separate documentation of change of name, taken together with the original marriage certificate, should suffice.

Comment: The strange thing is her Certificate of Naturalization doesn't really mention her old name anywhere. Just her new name.

Comment: Nevermind, there is another document attached that shows the name change.